Why can't I get a value from this simulation?

Why doesn't the simulation show any value?

Did you press run?

Give the capacitor C1 an initial condition (required to start the simulation in the time domain)

With tran you have to click on a signal to see a value. Your question is very unspecific, so we are all guessing...

Your .tran statement is a comment instead of a SPICE directive. But my guess is you’re having trouble getting this circuit to oscillate. Like others said, please include more details.

You could have an error
